# manipulate class instance

Tags: python, class, instance, instance-methods

I want to give the second instance of my Player class the remaining marker after the first instance gets one of them.

```
class Player():

    available_markers = ['X', 'O']

    num_of_players = 0

    player2_marker = ' '

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = input('Please enter your name : ')

        self.marker = ' '

        Player.num_of_players += 1

    def choose_marker(self):

        while Player.num_of_players != 2:

            self.marker = input('Choose X or O')
            if self.marker == Player.available_markers[0]:
                Player.player2_marker == Player.available_markers[-1]
            else:
                Player.player2_marker == Player.available_markers[0]
        else:
            self.marker = Player.player2_marke
```

I would like to accomplish this in the instance method but have went through a lot of code that doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some misunderstandings of object-oriented coding in your code so I'll try to address them in my answer. One of the goals of object-oriented programming is the separation of concerns. If you have some logic about how a game works and you have some logic about how a player works, you don't want the logic for both in the same place intermixed.

All the player really needs to know is what their name, marker and player number are:

```
class Player():
    num_of_players = 0

    def __init__(self, name, marker):
        Player.num_of_players += 1
        self.name = name
        self.marker = marker
        self.number = Player.num_of_players
        print(self.number, self.marker)
```

Separate from that is how you want to start the game and initialize the players. You could create another class called `Game` but for now, I'll just do a function:

```
def start_game():
    available_markers = ['X', 'O']
    print("Player 1")
    name = input('Please enter your name : ')
```

Let's not trust that the user of the program will enter the right thing:

```
    while True:
        marker = input('Choose X or O: ')
```

We will loop forever and just break out of it if a valid option is chosen:

```
        if marker in available_markers:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please pick again")

    player1 = Player(name, marker)
```

We'll remove that marker from the list so the list just has one element in it now:

```
    available_markers.remove(marker)
    print("Player 2")
    name = input('Please enter your name : ')
    player2 = Player(name, available_markers[0])

start_game()

# Player 1
# Please enter your name : Adam
# Choose X or O: X
# 1 X
# Player 2
# Please enter your name : Joe
# 2 O
```

Note that I create two separate instances of `Player`.

Let's talk briefly about class variables vs instant variables. I kept `num_of_players` as a class variable to track the total number of players (accessible by doing `Player.num_of_players` or `player1.num_of_players` both will return that there are 2 total players). I also created another variable `number` so each player can track what their number is. That's an instance variable and tracked separately for each instance.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks again. I was thinking that wasn't needed because we were handling the markers separately but leaving it in works to make player number 1 and player number 2 know which number they are.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me! Currently rewriting my classes and so far so good.